# Cannot boot after GRUB

Tags: boot, 14.04

Yesterday I was copying things from NFS to my computer and something was stuck, after a while I tried to restart my computer but it didn't work so i force powered it off.

Now, when I booted the machine, it got to GRUB and after it couldn't boot.

It seems like vmlinuz and initrd loading successfully (no matter what version - 3.13, 3.11 i tried both of them).

all i see at the beginning is empty screen and after a while it sometimes tells me that mount points are not ready (/tmp /boot /):

"The disk drive for [some mountpoint] is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery".

except for "/", it warns about all the mountpoints in fstab.

Also can see that "rpcsec_gss daemon" is failed to start.

At one of my attempts it told me that there are serious problems with /, so I used livecd and fsck the disk. didn't find anything special.

My questions are:
1. how can I debug the boot process verbosely and find what cause this problem?
2. what can cause this trouble?

By the way, i have Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem!

It seems like it was because of ldap service. i've installed openldap client and changed /etc/nsswitch.conf file to load users first from ldap identities (for example passwd ldap compat).

When I removed ldap from nsswitch.conf, the system got back booting again.

the suspected messages found in /var/log/syslog:

"May 10 12:22:13 iLaptop kernel: [ 1237.108870] type=1400 audit(1399713733.676:43): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" name="/etc/ldap/ldap.conf" pid=10490 comm="cups-browsed" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0" "

"May 10 12:22:14 iLaptop kernel: [ 1237.973672] type=1400 audit(1399713734.540:44): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/etc/ldap/ldap.conf" pid=10528 comm="dbus" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=7 ouid=0 "

Comment: Of course I used liveCD in order to read the files. mounted "/" partition and then found log files.